# Personalizar texto de notificiaciones

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy enviando un correo de activación cuando un usuario se registra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese texto se genera desde el archivo layout.blade.php con la siguiente instruccion

```
{{ Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($slot) }}
```

Quiero quitar la cadena "Hello!" y "Regards" ya que no se necesitan ¿Que archivo debo editar para lograr eso?

Comment: Hola, podrías poner el código del archivo que mencionas? si dices que de él se genera esta vista ahí debes borrar las lineas correspondientes al *hello* y lo otro que tienes marcado

Comment: { {{ Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($slot) }} }

Comment: Esta cadena es la que genera todo el bloque de texto y botón del mensaje.

Comment: No si eso lo entendí pero por lo general esas cadenas hacen referencia a algún archivo. En todo caso encontré este dos links en donde hacen referencia a lo creo que necesitas, revisa y ojalá te sirva, saludos [link 1](http://programandonet.com/questions/58850/laravel-5-4-como-personalizar-el-diseno-del-correo-electronico-de-notificacion) - [link 2](https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-customize-laravel-5-4-notification-email-templates-header-and-footer-158b1c7cc1c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que se observa es una notificación, que no es exactamente lo mismo que un Mail (lee la documentación para entender la diferencia).

Para poder modificar la plantilla en mención, debes ejecutar el siguiente comando primero:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

Posteriormente encontrarás la plantilla en la siguiente ruta:

> resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php

La documentación pertinente está en: https://laravel.com/docs/master/notifications

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes toda la razon, jamas se me ocurrio revisar la documentacion de notifications de laravel, simplemente utilice un otra vista que no fuera la que genera la notification. ¡Gracias!